# Under Floor Heating (Wet) - pipe coupler under the screed?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, pipe, central-heating

I want to fit UFH to a whole house - normally it would be an easy process if one could just move out and live somewhere else as the whole house gets gutted and re-done. However, ideally, i want to fit ufh o each room on a room by room basis so i still can live somewhere.

Now in room 1 I thought of doing this:
Lay down insulation, lay down the pipes and cut them as they leave the room into hallway, pour screed.

Then move onto room 2, room 3 etc.

At the end i would end up with all rooms having pipes installed and screed done but the hallways left (with all those pipes sticking out from each room into the hallway. I could potentially do Hallway last but this raises the question. Can i use pipe couplers to connect then all the rooms to the system(manifold in the hallway)? and submerge the couplers under the screed? Or the pipes have to go to each room directly from the manifold and there is no other way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use pipe couplers to connect then all the rooms to the system(manifold in the hallway)? and submerge the couplers under the screed?

With PEX pipe it depends on the fittings. Some fittings are rated for this (the crimp/slide ones), others are not (ie, the ones you screw on). Check your local code.

Personally though I wouldn't risk it. It would be easier to simply leave enough pipe in the corridor, then roll it and place it out of the way against the wall so no-one trips on it.

Comment: yeah you are right - just gonna leave enough pipe and not worry about couplers for the time being :)